# Is there a way to find out if the current frame is a keyframe in Premiere Elements 10?

Tags: video, video-editor, premiere

Sometimes I animate the properties of certain effects using keyframes. It's a really nice feature, but something has been bugging me about it. The Add/Remove keyframe button doesn't [tell me](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/premiere_elements_10_the_add_remove_keyframe_button_doesnt_provide_feedback) whether or not the current frame is an existing keyframe.

[image: Keyframe toggle]

Am I missing something here? Is there a good way to find out whether or not the current frame is a keyframe for a certain property? I'm using Premiere Elements 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/premiereelements/using/WS09e4b3c48f3a79fc19b622510385d4355c-7e8b.html#WS09e4b3c48f3a79fc19b622510385d4355c-7e8a) specifies how to view keyframes.

Comment: I didn't know you could make them visible in the timeline. Still though, they should probably make that a toggle button. Thanks!